# WSO2 Facebook authenticator does not work properly after recent Facebook API changes

Tags: facebook, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am facing exactly the same problem as it is described on issue

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5846

WSO2 Facebook authenticator does not work properly after recent Facebook API changes

As i see the problem is been already solved in the source code of facebook authenticator class . my question is witch is the best approach to fix the problem on a working 5.3.0 WSO2 identity server enviroment.

Is it to write and build a custom federated authenticator as it is described here
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+Federated+Authenticator

I am asking because as is see a 5.3.1-GA release is mentioned and i am wondering if it is going to be soon a new release.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fixed version of this issue is added to the WSO2 store.

Download the latest version of facebook authenticator from the [WSO2 store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/9edb106b-05ee-4810-8d47-81d0639f8c2b). The add the downloaded jar to the `repository/components/dropins` directory and remove the older version jar from the same directory.